# Ampersand Changed to "&amp;" in URL

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

I have a site I am working on and sometimes the URLs are being changed `&amp;id=X` rather than `&id=X`.  For example, `https://secure.domain.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&amp;id=15` .

I am not sure how this happening. Any help on how to get CiviCRM to recognize either is appreciated.

I am running CiviCRM - 4.6.24 and Drupal - 7.52.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Steve - I've edited the question so that it displays what I think you mean, but please check

Comment: Where are these URLs showing up?  Are they in emails?

Comment: It looked right when I previewed it.  It looks perfect now. Thank you for changing what you changed. The emails appear to be from different sources.  It is not all from MailChimp or something like that.  I only know its happening from the email from the error handling extension  (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-error-handler).  Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought, but is it an artefact of the error-handler extension itself?  Might be worth confirming in the webserver logs what is being received there.

Answer (score 2):

Steve, I'm not sure exactly how this is happening, but it sounds like something about your process is getting confused between HTML and plain text.

If I typed &id=X in a Wysiwyg editor, the HTML source for that would be 
&id=X (actually, what I wrote over there to the left was "& amp;id=X" but without the space. It was interpreted as HTML and the "& amp;" was rendered as "&" - talk about illustrating the confusion - apparently I needed to use "preformatted" in this wysiwyg editor!)

Is it possible that some of the parameters for your site were cut and pasted from html and it snuck in this way?

Can you elaborate on when this occurs? E.G. is this manifesting in browsers, or in emails sent by CiviMail, or in some other way?

Rick